# Can you force an FTP client to use binary from the server side

Tags: python, ftp

We have devices that run a proprietary FTP client on them. They retrieve media files (AVI videos and Images) as well as XML files from our web service utilizing a python based FTP server. The problem I'm having is that the FTP client wants to download the media files in ASCII mode instead of binary mode. I'd like to continue to use our python FTP server (pyftpdlib) but I can't figure out a way to force the client to use binary mode.

I've skimmed through the FTP RFC looking for a command/response sequence that would allow our FTP server to tell the FTP client to use binary instead of ASCII. Does such a command/response sequence exist?

Comment: no AFAIK there is no such command sequence on the server side... you can try to only deliver binary from the server-side but that could to very strange behaviour/crash on the client side if it expects ASCII... the only solution IMHO is to change the behaviour of the client!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the default behaviour or you ftp server by using a custom `FTPHandler` and overriding the `FTPHandler.ftp_TYPE(filetype)` method and this way force your server to serve file in binary mode `self._current_type = "i"`.

Comment: I use your approach, but Filezilla tried to use "TYPE A" for a file named "test", which was a zip archive, and it was corrupted. My server served it "as is", but the client read it in text mode. Changing the file to "test.dat" forced Filezilla to use "TYPE I" and fixed the issue. But the problem is, even though my server treats "TYPE A" like "TYPE I", the client side still corrupts the file.